# Using rates instead of counts for badges and other reputation related stuff?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I wanted to suggest that in addition to (or instead of) using number of up-votes or views or ... we can have rates over a month or a year so that newbies could have a chance to compete.

After a while people who have been a member would gather too much reputation (without any means to deflate it) and no newcomer would be able to compte with them.

WHAT'S WRONG WITH HAVING A BADGE FOR "Question with more than 1K visits in one month" or "highest up-vote increase of the month" or "Epic teacher, more than 50 answers in one month!".

Comment: We were all n00bs at one stage. We all managed to survive in the mean SO jungle. The key thing to remember is you will earn badges and rep if you stick around and contribute, you won't get anything simply for showing up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, this is not a competition. :) There is also no such thing as "too much reputation".

However, there are [reputation leagues](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation) that kind of do what you're proposing, although they're not affecting people's actual reputation scores.

Comment: Imagine in a few of years there would be people with 1M reputation. If you are a younger member of the community you won't have a chance to become a moderator or ...

Comment: @Ali - You picked an interesting post to reply to with that statement. Anna only has 7k of rep, but she's the current frontrunner in the [Stack Overflow moderator elections](http://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=primary#post-8045547), and she's already a mod on two SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: @KevinVermeer - Yes, but in real life reputation has a decay rate, if you have reputation and completely abandon the community you should know that you'd be "SLOWLY" replaced by newcomers. (Also she has 12.2K).

Comment: @Ali I have 12k here on meta, but not on SO itself. It doesn't really matter what your reputation is relative to other people. 7k is 7k regardless of whether another person has 1k, 10k, or 300k.

Comment: @AnnaLear , but it IS a competition, for more rep and respect!

Comment: @Ali People don't generally compete for respect. Respect is just earned. Other people having a high reputation score doesn't stop you from earning reputation of your own, so again... there's no competition. Just focus on asking good questions and giving good answers and you will gain both reputation and respect that you're looking for.